# Can I prevent thieves from unlocking Android's bootloader?

Tags: android, firmware, arm

I know that anything can be exploited. But let's say I want to prevent thieves that **do not have access to not openly available exploits**, to reset my phone so he can sell.

If no openly available exploits exist, then he'd be left with the options of factory resetting (which I opened a question about here: [Is Android's system recovery a firmware thing or Android thing? Can factory reset be prevented?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/242143/is-androids-system-recovery-a-firmware-thing-or-android-thing-can-factory-rese)) or flashing a brand new Android.

Is there a way I can prevent him of flashing a new OS at all? This, combined with not being able to factory reset, would render the phone useless (unless he sells its parts).

Comment: If you want to rephrase your question, you should edit the existing question rather than asking a new one.

Comment: Pixel and OnePlus requires **Enable OEM unlocking** from developer settings else the fastboot command to unlock bootloader won't be accepted. For that, the thief has to unlock your screen to enable that setting. If he finds out the screen lock, he can reuse the device.